# The version of the package is different from the current version this program supports

Tags: export, xml, import, spweb, version

Goog day,

I have the problem with site import between two site collections. SharePoint 2016. The site collections are from same SP Farm.
I exported the site "http://Coll1.xxx.com/career" using the Central Administration. In the Central Administration, I went to Backup and Restore > Export a site or list. 
Choose my site "http://Coll1.xxx.com/career", and click Start Export.
The Career.cmp and Career1.cmp files were created.
I run Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://Coll2.xxx.com/career" -Path c:\Career.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite

I saw the error: The DateTime represented by the string is out of range.

Ok, I exported career.cmp file to my desktop and changed the extension .cmp to .cab
Then I changed

to

Now I repackaged it as a .cab file. I used a software called CabPack. Changed the extension .cab to .cmp

Run the command:

Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://Coll2.xxx.com/career" -Path c:\Career.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite

Get the error: the version of the package   is different from the current version this program supports, 15.0.0.0

Ok, I open the SystemData.XML file with an editor like NotePad++ 
And I see

```
<SchemaVersion Version="15.0.0.0" Build="16.0.4783.1000" DatabaseVersion="4108407" SiteVersion="15" ObjectsProcessed="579" />
```

I can't understand what can I change in SystemData.XML, if Version="15.0.0.0"
The Error message doesn't include information: "the version of the package ??? is different"

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: The question is still actual. I use the script http://codecaching.blogspot.com/2012/11/importing-cmp-and-string-was-not.html I get this: Cannot find path 'C:\TMP\Career\Manifest.cmp' because it doesn't exist.  

I have 51 Career.cmp files.

Comment: I opened site settings->site administration->Regional settings. They are same for Col1 and Col2. TimeZone (UTC+03:00) <my city> (RTZ 2)

I opened regional settings for Farm PC Windows 10. I see Format:

Short date: dd.mm.yyyy

Long date: d MMMM yyyy 'y'

Short time: H:mm

Long time: H:mm:ss

First day of week: Monday

Location: my country.
I don't understand which time settings are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I use -NoFileCompession.

I run

Export-SPWeb -Identity "My Site URL" -Path "My folder path" -NoFileCompression

I get files without compression, then I change in Manifest.xml

Then I run Import-SPWeb -Identity "My Site URL" -Path "My folder Path" -NoFileCompression

And the site was imported without problem.